# Existe uma forma de melhorar as respostas dessa pergunta?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Há algum tempo eu tenho me deparado com [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/400/20615), de **Como buscar um endereço por CEP nos Correios.**

Ela foi protegida pelo **Bigown**, o que já é um começo. Porém, existem várias respostas que "dizem a mesma coisa" praticamente.

A [resposta do Marcelo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33633/20615) faz uma lista com alguns web services, o que já é um caminho e estará sempre em modificações. Já outras respostas mostram como utilizar alguns modelos, o que é muito bom também.

O que eu não gostei é o fato de ter várias respostas que dizem a mesma coisa e que talvez não digam nada.

Mas, minha dúvida mesmo é: **Existe alguma forma de melhorar?**

Comment: Acho pouco provável. Essa pergunta como um todo sempre me incomodou. Eu acho que é o tipo de pergunta que não ajuda, pleo menos na forma atual, é só uma lista de *links* de coisas que existem num dia, não existem mais no outro, muito irregulares, ilegais, a qualidade é questionável e variável ao longo do tempo. Vamos ver se alguém dá alguma sugestão boa.

Comment: @bigown Eu nunca gostei da forma que ela está. Acho que se fosse aberta hoje, provavelmente seria fechada por vários fatores. Mas, esperamos para ver se alguém tem alguma ideia de como melhorar.

Comment: Concordo, mas parece que somos poucos.

Comment: Acredito que paguei uma recompensa por essa pergunta, e não obtive resposta, hoje eu utilizo o WebService dos Correios (Aplicação Delphi) frequentemente me questiono se devo responder lá com minha solução!

Comment: @bigown Olha a questão [se repetindo aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160517/20615)

Comment: @Randrade fechei, vamos ver o que acontece.

Comment: É uma pergunta que deveria ser respondida pelos Correios, mas não é. As respostas ali são boas, colocam todas as alternativas possíveis e expõem a problemática de uma coisa que deveria ser básica, padrão, pública e gratuita.